# iOS7: UILabel constantly redraw itself on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

CoreData returns BOOL value and according to the value I draw a UILabel on UITableViewCell accessoryView. The problem is that UILabel repeats itself also on the cells it shouldn't appear at all.

```
CGRect lblRect = CGRectMake(230, 7, 20, 20);
    UILabel *lblEnabled = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lblRect];
    lblEnabled.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    lblEnabled.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [lblEnabled setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:10.0]];
    [lblEnabled setText:@"40"];
    lblEnabled.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenBg"]];
    lblEnabled.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0;
    lblEnabled.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    lblEnabled.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.accessoryView = lblEnabled;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblEnabled];
```

So it appears sometimes on the cell where the `BOOL value = NO`; Your help is strongly appreciated.

EDIT: I draw these labels in cellForRowForIndexPath.

EDIT: I use storyboards, so I don't check if cell is nil.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell =
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

/*
if(cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    tableView.rowHeight=57.0;
}*/

Coin *coin=[[self frcFromTV:tableView ] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text=coin.coinNominal;

if(coin.comSubject.length>0)
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ (%@) | %@",[self returnCatalogDefinition:coin.catalogIndex],coin.kmRef, coin.dates, coin.comSubject];
}
else
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ | %@",[self returnCatalogDefinition:coin.catalogIndex],coin.kmRef,coin.dates];
}

if(coin.isCommemorative.boolValue)
{
    // implement label
}

if(coin.listed.boolValue)
{
    CGRect lblRect = CGRectMake(230, 7, 20, 20);
    UILabel *lblEnabled = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lblRect];
    lblEnabled.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    lblEnabled.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [lblEnabled setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:10.0]];
    [lblEnabled setText:@"40"];
    lblEnabled.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenBg"]];
    lblEnabled.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0;
    lblEnabled.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    lblEnabled.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.accessoryView = lblEnabled;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblEnabled];
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are not dealing properly with a method responsible for creating and updating existing cells, your problem occurs because cells in tableview are reusable, show code for updating cell and I will be show exactly what you are missing

Comment: Ok. Please see the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code below you probably add your label but because those cells are reusable you should handle else statement (hiding label or whatever is appropriate)

```
if(coin.isCommemorative.boolValue)
{
    // implement label
    //remove from that part of the statement this line:
    //[cell.contentView addSubview:lblEnabled];
} else {
     cell.accessoryView = nil;
    //hiding or modifying label for other cases
}
```

if you will not deal with that else statement the change you made in if will be applicable to more than one cell because of the reusing mechanism

As a "side advice" I would recommend you to subclass UITableViewCell and add the property you want (label) to encapsulate that and make only public method for showing or hiding that accessor.

EDIT:
if your flag for a change is not specifying to which cell it has to indicate (for example using indexPath) then the result is as your one.

This is quite global state `if(coin.isCommemorative.boolValue)` not indicating to which cell it counts try for example (for just learning purpose) add `if(coin.isCommemorative.boolValue && indexPath.row%2==0)` and see the result.

Comment: The devil lives is if(coin.listed.boolValue) spot. If BOOL=YES I draw the label and if not I do nothing… so what more I can do?

Comment: okay I got it. But once you add it it exist in some of the cell as long as for some case you are not going to hide it! Make a subclass of UITableViewCell to have a reference to hide it or add a tag to the label and then look up for a view with that tag and hide it. Moreover I do not know why you are adding it twice:
     `cell.accessoryView = lblEnabled;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblEnabled];`

Comment: you can try in else statement do this 
`cell.accessoryView.hidden = YES;` or `cell.accessoryView` sorry I'm out for compiler so might be not 100% precise

Comment: I tried cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; it makes the same.

Comment: Ok. nil works and makes miracles. Thank you, I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you reusing cells? If so, then you need to remove that cell from contentView inside `prepareForReuse` method.